# .htaccess to control Wordpress and Yii2 application

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I have an application that I have written in Yii2.  I now need to install this on a web server that is currently hosting Wordpress.  The directory looks something like this:

```
/
    /customer-account
        /web  (Yii application lives here)
    /gswp     (Wordpress application lives here)
    ...
```

The .htaccess file in the root directory currently looks something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^$ customer-account/web/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*) customer-account/web/$1 [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It's worth pointing out that the WP site is working fine.  Also, Yii2 is using pretty URLs, so has it's own .htaccess magic happening in /web.  All of the requests to WP are dropping through to its directory.  Calls to /customer-account/web that do not hit an actual directory, are generating the WP 404 page.  I have successfully placed this project under a plain old PHP application.  You can see from above that I've taken a few stabs at making the magic happen, but no joy so far.

I simply want all requests that hit /customer-account/web/* to be passed through to `web` so it can do the rest. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up going with in the root directory, hopefully it will help someone:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Yii
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /customer-account/web
RewriteRule .* customer-account/web/index.php [NC,L,QSA]

# Wordpress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

And in the Yii2 directory /customer-account/web :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /customer-account/web/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```